# 'Connection was forcibly closed  by the remote host' when sending a lot of data

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, apple-push-notifications, socketexception

I have some troubles with the sending of push notifications in a C# multithread windows service.
When I send a lot of notifications to the APNS, some of threads throws an exception :

```
Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Write(Byte[] buffer) ...
```

I have a threadPool of 16 threads, and each thread open a connexion to Apple.

 It's not a timeout because i have tried with : `sslStream.WriteTimeout = 60000;`

 I have also tried with: `Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, false);`

**The connection is not closed at the beginning of the sending.**

**EDIT :** I think that all data are sent, and Apple close the connection suddenly.

Have you an idea of the origin of this exception ?
How resolve it ?

I can give you some code if it's needed.

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution, but I think that is Apple who close the connexion in order to reuse the socket, when no more data are sent.

To avoid errors, I use enhanced notifications now.

Answer (score 4):

The exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" typically means that the other host you had the connection open to decided not to talk to you any more. To do this it sends a FIN with RST set to shut down the connection from its end.

Since this happens when you send a lot of notifications, is it possible the service is deliberately throttling you to prevent an overload?

Comment: I think that it's not a throttling because the Apple notification service manages lot of notifications. And this not happens on every threads, even if other threads send the same number of notifications.

Comment: Okay, if it isn't thottling it is some other reason.  Whatever the reason, APNS is deciding it doesn't want to talk to you anymore.  APNS is shutting down the connection and your program is getting the exception when it tries to use the connection that's no longer open.

Comment: If the thread throws an exception, the write operation is not finished, isn't it?

Comment: Certainly the data passed into the write operation has not been delivered.  It is also possible that data sent in previous write operations has not been delivered.  We can't be sure because we don't know when the APNS sent the RESET and we don't know how much data (if any) it chose to read before sending the RESET.

Comment: So, there is no solution to know how bytes have been sent.

Comment: There's no solution just using the sockets API.  If APNS sends you some sort of acknowledgement then you know it received whatever bytes it acknowledges but otherwise you just don't know if the bytes got through - even if the Write is successful.

Answer (score 1):

From APNS-Sharp I've seen that users have seen this error when they've passed in bad device tokens - http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/issues/detail?id=35

If that's not the answer, then can you confirm that your code doesn't work when you open less threads? Or does it work when you send smaller quantities of data?

As an aside on this, is it really necessary to open 16 connections at the same time? This seems quite high.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read this post. His problem is solved by using a higher timeout. I have write my own implementation for sending  a lot of notifications (500k per message). So I open 16 connexions (ax 20). Bad device tokens are removed before the sending, and token are disabled with the feedback service.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with push notifications, but I recently experienced this problem in a multi-threaded application, because I had a socket that was shared between two threads (one for sending data and one for receiving). While the receiving thread was blocking in a socket.ReceiveFrom(), the sending thread was attempting to send data on the same socket. This caused the "Connection forcibly closed by the remote host" error in my application. This might be something that you should look in to.

I ended up fixing my problem by adding some a WaitHandles to make the socket connection thread safe.

Comment: But I don't read the response after the sending, I close the connexion just after the `write`. I use threadpool, and I declare a ssl stream in each thread, so I think that sockets are not shared.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are having too many open connections and the server at apple for whatever reason closes them.
Try to see if the problems persists with less # of connections.

Comment: Apple allows 20 connections. So to prevent too many connections problem, I have restricted to 16 the number of them. There is a way to know how many connections are opened at the same time ?